# How to mount OpenStack container in a Docker container

Tags: docker, openstack

I am new to [OpenStack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack). I saw there is a feature called containers in OpenStack. I think those containers are not the same thing as Docker containers. I have understood OpenStack containers are just file storage (volume?) Right or wrong?

But is there a way to mount an OpenStack container in a Docker container?

I want to have a Docker container which contains only "system files" (/bin, /usr, apache, mysql) and to put all my configuration files and PHP files in an OpenStack container.

Comment: A docker image containers a containers file system, Docker make it easy to add files to a new image using the Dockerfile syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Containers in OpenStack are applied to the Object Storage (OpenStack SWIFT). Swift is the OpenStack-counterpart of AWS S3. What you call "Bucket" in S3, is a "container" in SWIFT.

Nevertheless, OpenStack is including "docker-container" support trough two projects:

- Nova-Docker (Compute component in NOVA, wotking at "hypervisor" level, but whith docker instead of KVM/QEMU/Libvirt)
- OpenStack Magnum: Docker-container orchestration solution for OpenStack.

You can see any of those projects at:

- Magnum: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum
- Nova-docker: https://github.com/openstack/nova-docker